# How to remote debug a java process running on the play framework

Tags: java, playframework, remote-debugging

I'm using play 2.1.2 and Java 1.7 on Eclipse.

This is a two part question.
1) How do we remote debug a process that's running on the play framework
2) How do I restrict the debug port to one of many play processes running on the server?

I'm trying to debug our website that's running off the play framework.  We want to do a remote debug on it.  I was told to add some JAVA_OPTS so we could do that but we are running two play processes for this website, one for the UI, and one for the query API.  If I define JAVA_OPTS to debug on a specific port, I think all play processes will be using that port for debugging.  How do I make play allow us to debug the UI process so that the debug port is only used by the UI process?

What we're doing in our script is executing

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8765"
cd to_UI_dir
play start -Dhttps.port=9004 -Dhttps.keystorePassword=blah etc.
cd to_API_dir
play start -Dhttps.port=9007 -Dhttps.keystorePassowrd=blah2 etc.
```

Second problem is this:
When we run `ps -ef | grep debug` on this, the java command run by play doesn't match what we defined int he JAVA_OPTS.

> user    3500  3490 99 13:26 ?        00:37:43 java -Xms512M -Xmx1536M
>   -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=384M -Xdebug -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dplay.version=2.1.2 -Dsbt.ivy.home=/glide/bigdata/play-2.1.2/framework/../repository -Dplay.home=/glide/bigdata/play-2.1.2/framework -Dsbt.boot.properties=/glide/bigdata/play-2.1.2/framework/sbt/sbt.boot.properties
>   -jar /glide/bigdata/play-2.1.2/framework/sbt/sbt-launch.jar start --Dhttps.port=9004 -Dhttps.keyStore=conf/stats.jks -Dhttps.keyStorePassword=password -Dconfig.resource=ssl.conf

Here, we just see the -Xdebug option but not the other things we defined.  How do we make play use all the JAVA_OPTS we defined so we can debug the process?

Comment: Have you tried `activator -jvm-debug <port> run` ?
See this https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlayConsole#debugging

Comment: @ArpitSuthar, Thanks for helping.  Sorry, I forgot to mention I'm using play 2.1.2.  I don't think it's available at my version.

Comment: if you are using 2.1.x see this
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/PlayConsole#Debugging